# class client not found emojione when using on codenigter

Tags: php, codeigniter, emojione

Hello Experts I am in a big problem I am using emojione library to convert short name to image the emojis works fine when using on code php but i want this to use with codegniter i decided to created a model so i can easily access on al over for that I created a function inside my EmojiModel.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EmojiModel extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         require APPPATH . 'third_party/emojione/LoadEmojione.php';
    }

    public function LoadImageEmoji($mojiText) {
        $emoji = new \EmojiLoad();
        return $emoji->LoadImageEmoji($mojiText);
    }
}
```

inside third party library I hade added the library and created a file named LoadEmoji.php and simply included that file inside model constructor

application\third_party\emojione\LoadEmojione.php

```
namespace Emojione;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class EmojiLoad {
    public function LoadImageEmoji($textEmoji) {
        $client = new Client(new Ruleset());
        $client->imagePathPNG = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.4/assets/png/'; 
        return $client->toImage($textEmoji);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class "EmojiLoad" not found

I am not sure what should I do because it is important in this library to use namespace i am confused what should I do here

Comment: Change this line `$emoji = new \EmojiLoad();` to `$emoji = new \Emojione\EmojiLoad();`. Your `EmojiLoad` class is in the `Emojione` namespace, so you need to add the namespace before the classname when using it.

Comment: Why is it required to add the extra `LoadEmojione.php` inside the library? You can directly use it in model

Comment: @Marleen can you post as answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line `$emoji = new \EmojiLoad();` to `$emoji = new \Emojione\EmojiLoad();`. Your `EmojiLoad` class is in the `Emojione` namespace, so you need to add the namespace before the classname when using it.

---

Alternatively, as shirshak007 suggested, if you're only using your custom `EmojiLoad` class in the `EmojiModel` class, you can also use the `Emoijone` library directly in the model.

In that case I would also suggest using CodeIgniter's `composer_autoload` function:

In `application/config/config.php`, set `$config['composer_autoload']` to `TRUE`.

This expects the `composer.json` file to live in the `application` folder, so copy it there from the `application/third_party/emojione` folder and then delete the `application/third_party/emojione` folder. If you then do `composer install` from the `application` folder, it'll create a new `vendor` folder inside the `application` folder.

Then use the `Emojione` library directly in the model:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Emojione\Client;
use Emojione\Ruleset;

class EmojiModel extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
    }

    public function LoadImageEmoji($mojiText) {
        $client = new Client(new Ruleset());
        $client->imagePathPNG = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.1.4/assets/png/'; 
        return $client->toImage($mojiText);
    }
}
```